# Strange java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java, netbeans-7, classcastexception

I use Java and Netbeans 7.2 
This is a simple JFrame form. It connects to SQLite database, retrieves all records from one table and puts it into JTable widget (Table1). It works fine.

However, I added 4 text fields that are supposed to be filled with values of a row that has been clicked on in the JTable.

When the click handler starts it inserts just the first column value in the first text field and then the error message pops up saying (java.lang.ClassCastException).

I just can not figure out which row is the problem. Debugger prints error about "uncompilable code" (I dont know how to use debugger).

```
private void Table1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)      {                                    

    try{
        int row = Table1.getSelectedRow();
        String rowId = (Table1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        String sql = "select * from ljudi where ID='"+rowId+"';";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rst = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rst.next()){

            String name = rst.getString("ime");
            String surname = rst.getString("prezime");
            String address = rst.getString("adresa");
            String telephone = rst.getString("telefon");

            txt_ime.setText(name);
            txt_prezime.setText(surname);
            txt_adresa.setText(address);
            txt_telefon.setText(telephone);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

I even commented all code inside the method, the Output window shows error messages as soon as I click on a table row.

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2990)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(Binding.java:1312)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.getSourceValueForTarget(Binding.java:844)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refreshUnmanaged(Binding.java:1222)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refresh(Binding.java:1207)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.tryRefreshThenSave(AutoBinding.java:162)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.sourceChangedImpl(AutoBinding.java:227)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.sourceChanged(Binding.java:1411)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.access$1200(Binding.java:38)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding$PSL.propertyStateChanged(Binding.java:1618)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.PropertyHelper.firePropertyStateChange(PropertyHelper.java:212)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.notifyListeners(ELProperty.java:688)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.access$800(ELProperty.java:155)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.processSourceChanged(ELProperty.java:312)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.sourceChanged(ELProperty.java:326)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.propertyChange(ELProperty.java:333)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:339)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:276)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.BeanAdapterBase.firePropertyChange(BeanAdapterBase.java:112)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.JTableAdapterProvider$Adapter$Handler.tableSelectionChanged(JTableAdapterProvider.java:81)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.JTableAdapterProvider$Adapter$Handler.valueChanged(JTableAdapterProvider.java:91)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:167)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:147)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:194)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:388)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:398)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:442)
at javax.swing.JTable.changeSelectionModel(JTable.java:2352)
at javax.swing.JTable.changeSelection(JTable.java:2421)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicTableUI.java:1085)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1008)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:263)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:262)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6264)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4235)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

P.S. The full stack trace is here as you asked, I suppose that is it.

P.P.S.
I solved it in a bit different way:

```
try 
    {
    int pozicija = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    String rowId = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(pozicija, 0).toString();

    String ime = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(pozicija,1).toString();

    String prezime = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(pozicija,2).toString();

    String adresa = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(pozicija,3).toString();

    String telefon = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(pozicija,4).toString();


    jTextField1.setText(ime);
    jTextField2.setText(prezime);
    jTextField3.setText(adresa);
    jTextField4.setText(telefon);
    jLabel2.setText(rowId);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Instead of running a query on a database, I used the same field values from jTable model. Works fine and the purpose of this is to populate text fields for editing the record.

I don't think it would be necessary to query the db again?

Btw. I saw the first example on a youtube tutorial by "ProgrammingKnowledge". It has many basic stuff explained.

Thank you for the ideas.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: What is jdesktop? Is that a netbeans specific thing?

Comment: The method that threw the Exception: `...beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(...)` means your UI is trying to automatically convert the type of "something" (from the database) into "something else" that the UI expects. I know netbeans can hook some of these auto-bindings up for you, but I'm not familiar with how to edit/verify them. Perhaps you changed the expected class on accident? Or (more likely), you're doing something like binding a `String` into a checkbox/radiobox--and they expect `boolean`s--or a `String` into a numeric spinner--and it expects an `integer`.

Comment: Since the first column is populated OK, definitely check for bindings in the second column.